# Adding Google Maps to website with MapInnovations

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to integrate Google Maps on to my website, but the Google Maps api is a little bit complicated (for getting driving directions to show up).  I'm wondering if anyone has had success using the tool from MapInnovations, as I've seen it on a couple of sites but I'm having some trouble getting the directions box to show up on my page.  I put the addressbox div in the body tag and the other piece of code before my HTML tag, but all that shows up is a grey line.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Where exactly did you place the reference to the javascript? "Before the HTML tag" is a little vague. Personally, I've used MapInnovations without any difficultly and know many developers who think it's incredibly simple to integrate. I'm guessing it's a small problem that should be a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with MapInnovations, but [MapStraction](http://mapstraction.com/) one of the standards for map abstraction.

Comment: MapStraction seems to be more of a development kit...too complicated for me unfortunately.  This MapInnovations tool seems simple...I must be making a small mistake in my code though